# How to redirect to external https site?

Tags: nginx, proxypass

Part of my nginx conf.d as shown below. proxy_pass to internal networks working. Cant redirect to external site.

I need to **redirect** this

**$host = my.website.com/admin** to 
**proxy_pass "https://admin.myothersite.com/httpsms"**;

and I am keep getting 404 error.

How to redirect to external https site?

```
server {

…….
……..
………

 // WORKS
   if ($host =my.website.com/login) {
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }

// WORKS
   if ($host = my.website.com/admin) {
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }
}



server {

…….
……..
………


// WORKS
    location /login {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }


// ITS NOT WORKING
    location /admin {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "https://admin.myothersite.com/httpsms";
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to redirect to external https site?

if you want to *redirect* you shouldnt use proxy pass. just use return 301;

```
location /admin {
    return 301 https://admin.myothersite.com/httpsms;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much easier than I thought. Regards

Comment: @Nick you should accept this as your answer if it worked.

Comment: I did, Thanks a lot.